# Problem running c++ project in eclipse, Red Hat Linux

Tags: c++, linux, eclipse, qt4, makefile

I am trying to run a c++ project in Red Hat Linux using eclipse. I am getting the following error:

```
Description Resource    Path    Location    Type
make: *** [Makefile] Error 3                C/C++ Problem
```

can anybody help me solving this?

Comment: There are errors before this. What are they?

Comment: This looks like the output as shown in the problems tab which often leaves out errors it doesn't understand. Can you post the output of the Console tab? Make sure to include the first error showing up on the console not just the last few.

Comment: Console Output

QMAKESPEC has not been set, so configuration cannot be deduced.

Error Processing project file: abc.pro
make: *** [MAKEFILE] Error 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

set environment variable QMAKESPEC as us want like 'linux-g++' or whatever you want
use export QMAKESPEC=linux-g++ to set the variable